# Incrementing php variable after calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

Let's have a database of items. Each item has its unsigned integer `id`( 1,2,.. ). Next we have a page which prints all the items and can add new items ( just temporarily - only with javascript - not into database ). When we get to this page, it prints items like this:

1. Item
2. Item
3. Item

After all of these items there is a button "Add item"( this button has `onclick` `javascript function` ). When I click on that button twice, list should change this way:

1. Item
2. Item
3. Item
4. Item
5. Item

How is it possible to do this? First time when I post all the items from database, I know `id` of each one so `php` can remember the highest one. But when an item needs to be created, `php` passes argument ( the highest `id` variable with pre-incrementing ) into `javascript function` which creates a new element and prints it. But every time when the `Add item` `button` is clicked, `php variable` with the highest id is increased from `3` to `4` - this variable is temporarily increased - when `Add item` `button` is clicked multiple times, each new item has number `4`.

Is there any way to not only temporarily increment this variable?

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addChoice( last_id )
    {
        var choice = document.createElement( "input" );
        choice . setAttribute( "type", "text" );
        var p = document.createElement( "p" );
        p . innerHTML = last_id + ".";
        var form = document.getElementById( "new_questions" );

        form . appendChild( p );
        form . appendChild( choice );

        for( var i = 0; i < 1; i ++ )
        {
            var br = document.createElement( "br" );
            form . appendChild( br );
        }
    }
</script>
<?php
    $subjects = $mysql->query( "SELECT * FROM subjects" );

    $questionNr = $_POST["question"];
    $question = $mysql->query( "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_number='$questionNr';" );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $question );

    $choices = $mysql->query( "SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question_number='$questionNr';" );
?>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="quizzer_edit" method="post" action="process_edit.php">
                <label>Subject</label>
                <select name="subject">
                    <?php while( $rowSubject = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $subjects ) ) { ?>
                        <option <?php if( $row["subject"] == $rowSubject["shortcut"] ) echo 'selected="selected"' ?> value=<?php echo $rowSubject["shortcut"] ?>><?php echo $rowSubject["name"] ?></option>
                    <? } ?>
                </select><br>
                <p><?php echo $row["text"]; ?></p>
                <input type="text" name="new_question"/>
                <?php while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $choices ) ) { ?>
                    <p><?php echo $row["id"].".".$row["text"]; ?></p>
                    <input type="text" name=<?php echo $row["id"]; $last_id = $row["id"];?>/>
                    <strong>Correct </strong>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_correct"/>
                <?php } ?>

                <div id="new_questions"></div>
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Add choice" onclick="addChoice(<?php echo ++$last_id; ?>)"/><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to show some code :) That will get you the right answer a lot faster

Comment: you want to make, something like dynamic textboxes?

Comment: @Rishi I am doing text boxes in code but the thing I need is to just save the incremented value of variable from php after each click on button which start javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already done it:

I had to declare a new javascript variable `last_id` before declaration of function `addChoice()`.

In the end of file I had to assign a value to this variable:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  last_id = <?php echo $last_id ?>;
</script>`

And then I set `onclick="addChoice( ++last_id )"`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Javascript function you call is inside the page that displays the results.

If so, you could use two fields (variables declared outside the function), that store:

1. is this the first time, the js-function is called (firstRun)
2. the next number to give to an entry (counter)

On the first call, you set the counter to the argument given by php, on consecutive calls `firstRun == false` you simply increment the counter and use it, ingoring the argument.

Comment: I am thinking about it but how can I save content of php variable into javascript variable outside of javascript function?